# Why is my Rails App defaulting to SQLite3 instead of PSQL on digitalocean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, development-environment, digital-ocean

When I try to create a rails app on DigitalOcean (Ubuntu/Nginx/passenger) it always defaults to sqlite3 and I get an error message in the browser:

`SQLite3::CantOpenException`

But when I use WebBrick locally it works fine running on PostGres.  What could be causing this and how can I get my app to use PostGres?  It's installed on DigitalOcean and I can migrate and seed the database in my app, it just seems to want to use sqlite3.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The database configuration is in config/database.yml:

```
adapter: sqlite3
```

should be:

```
adapter: postgresql
```

Without seeing your database.yml I'd guess you have development setup with postgres but not production.

Comment: My adapter is set to postgresql in database.yml and I don't see any other options for default anywhere in database.yml.

Comment: Are you setting it for each env?  Can you post a copy of database.yml?

**Remove your passwords first**

Comment: Ok, I posted my full database.yml file.  It didn't have any usernames or passwords actually.

Comment: I don't seen anything obvious there but what about explicitly setting adapter in the production hash?